# my login page is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to make login page. i store some data in the database. when i enter the data then it will show the error which i don't know y is coming because i define the index.....

*php code*

> ```
>   //var_dump($_POST);
>   // Grab User submitted information
>
>
>   $user = $_POST["username"];
>   $pass = $_POST["password"];
>
>   if(empty($user) && empty($pass))
>   {
>
>       $msg = "Pleae enter username and password";
>   }
>   else
>   {
>   // Connect to the database
>   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","jj");
>   // Make sure we connected succesfully
>   if(! $con)
>   {
>       session_start();
>   $_SESSION['Logged in'] = true;
>       die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
>   }
>
>   // Select the database to use
>   mysql_select_db("jj");
>
>   $qry = "SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username = '".$user."' and password = '".$pass."'";
>   echo $qry;
>
>
>   $result = mysql_query($qry);
>
>   //var_dump($result);
>   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
>
>
>
>   //var_dump($row);  //check the row 
>   if($row["username"]==$user && $row["password"]==$pass)
>       {
>           $msg = "You are a validated user.";
>
>
>           session_start();
>
>           $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
>
>           $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
>
>           header("Location: Iphoneunlockingcenter.html");
>           die();
>       }
>   else
>       {
>           $msg ="Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";
>       }
>
>
>   }
>   }
>
> ?>
> ```

when i try to login then error comes 
which the pic is showing
[image]

Comment: Please fix your code. Don't use `>`, use 4+ spaces followed by a line of code.

Comment: I see where you are trying to assign a session key from the results of your query, but I struggle to see where you have tried to use a key of `password` in your code. Please post relevant code to your questions body

Comment: Undefined index errors can be a few things. Form elements not named, or contains typos. Or, a bad GET method from a fetch.

Comment: After trying to sort out your questions formatting. It's clear you have unclosed quotes, I would review your code as the flagged notices would be the least of your problems

Comment: You're also using `session_start();` twice.

Comment: ok but when i try to log in other code this code is working well

Comment: Did you check that `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` actually existed *before* trying to read them?  [`isset`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is your friend.

Comment: @Fred-ii- session_start() will never be executed twice. After the first one he's killing the script two lines later with `die()`. But his header(); will output something like `Headers already sent ...`. Deprecated mysql_* functions, cleartext passwords, code prone to sql injection, not checking input (see Mr. Llama), ... It's a great list of defects to work at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use ISSET.

try replace this

```
  $user = $_POST["username"];
  $pass = $_POST["password"];
```

by

```
  if(isset($_POST["username"]) and isset($_POST["password"])){
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]); //escape your variables
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
     }
   else {
      $user = '';
      $pass = '';
   }
```